# Comparing empty string to int

Tags: c++, string

```
string line, operation, sec, third;
int first;
getline(cin, line);
istringstream(line) >> operation >> first >> sec >> third;
```

the program reads a command from the user then acts according to the operation specified 
some operation takes only one parameter

```
>>operation_name first_argument
```

if the user didn't enter first_argument the program will give error message,
the thing is with what should I compare first with
I've tried to compare it with 0 but it didn't work !!!

Comment: don't read more than you need.

Comment: Do you mean empty string? Because `std::string` (which you use) cannot be `NULL`, while `char*` **can**?

Comment: the second word in the line is empty not the whole line

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if(!line.empty())` to ensure that the string is not empty

See link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/empty/

Comment: I want to check if first is empty,but if I change it to string then tried if(!first.empty()) it didn't work

Comment: If you want to 'check if first IS empty' use if ( first.empty() ) ... The ! is the same a NOT or NOT EQUAL... remove it and try again.  Post your new code to your question...it helps everyone see how you are progressing

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize the 'first' variable e.g.

int first = -1;

Then compare first against -1 after the user has entered the command. (Assuming -1 is not a valid input argument.)